# Turn multiple repetitive MySQL queries into one?

Tags: mysql, optimization, sql-order-by

```
UPDATE some_table set rank=1 WHERE id=25
UPDATE some_table set rank=2 WHERE id=15
UPDATE some_table set rank=3 WHERE id=10
UPDATE some_table set rank=4 WHERE id=12
UPDATE some_table set rank=5 WHERE id=13
UPDATE some_table set rank=6 WHERE id=14
UPDATE some_table set rank=7 WHERE id=11
```

How can I turn this into a single query because I couldn't think of one? These values of `id` are in sequence. Think of a photo gallery that has images and the user can opt to re-arrange the sequence of these images. The back-end will assign the ranks based from the user-defined sequence and will be used in the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: What issue are you trying to solve by putting them in a single query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
update some_table 
set rank = case 
    when id = 25 then 1 
    when id = 15 then 2
    when id = 10 then 3 
    when id = 12 then 4
    when id = 13 then 5 
    when id = 14 then 6 
    when id = 11 then 7 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a case structure...similar to this..

```
CASE id1
    WHEN id = 25 THEN UPDATE some_table SET rank = 1
ELSE
    WHEN id = 15 THEN UPDATE some_table SET rank = 2
ELSE
    etc...
END CASE
```

Reference:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE p()
BEGIN
DECLARE v INT DEFAULT 1;

CASE v
  WHEN 2 THEN SELECT v;
  WHEN 3 THEN SELECT 0;
  ELSE
    BEGIN
    END;
END CASE;
END;
|
```